# google recaptcha v2 in livewire component comes with issues

Tags: php, recaptcha, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to implement **google recaptcha v2** with livewire but I get some issues :

The issue that I get is when I try to call **RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY** from the **.env** file it display me this error message in **Dev Console** :

> "Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey"

it confusing because the site key is correct and is already exist inside **.env** file.

Wile I remove the **{{ env('RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY') }}** from **data-sitekey** and add the site key it work

**Not Working example :**

```
data-sitekey="{{ env('RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY') }}"

"Uncaught Error: Missing required parameters: sitekey"
```

**Working example :**

```
data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

> Where this problem coming from ?

Answer (score 0):

First, double check that is is spelled exactly the same in your .env. Second, run `php artisan cache:clear` in case your config is cached. Third, attempt `env('RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY');` from `php artisan tinker` and see what results you get.